# No MediaQuery widget ancestor found while using MediaQuery.of(context)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an error saying **No MediaQuery widget ancestor found while using MediaQuery.of(context)**. Here is my code and I am using **MediaQuery.of(context)** inside a MaterialApp but it is still giving me errors. Can someone help?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Responsive'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: mediaQuery.size.height,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                height: 200,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error**

[image: error image]

Comment: you can call `MediaQuery.of` only for `context` that is a child (direct or indirect) of `MaterialApp` - so for example: `runApp(MaterialApp(body: MyApp(), ...))`

Comment: didn't get that. Can you please provide a working code snippet so that I can understand it?

Comment: i already gave you: instead of `void main() => runApp(MyApp());` do `void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(body: MyApp()));` (and of course remove `MaterialApp` from `MyApp`)

Comment: ooops, sorry, it should be `home:` of course, not `body:`

Comment: Yeah! I tried this ```void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: MyApp())));``` and it worked, but is this a good practice to include this much of stuff in main function?

Comment: run `flutter create fooooo` and check how it should be done in `fooooo/lib/main.dart` - it creates 2 classes: one `StatelessWidget` that builds `MaterialApp` and one `StatefulWidget` which builds the rest (you can also use https://dartpad.dartlang.org/flutter and press `NewPad` button)

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because your `MediaQuery` is out of `MaterialApp`. Use material home as seperate Stateless of Statefull widget.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home();
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Responsive'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: mediaQuery.size.height,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              height: 200,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use media Query like that

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
```

and where you want to use so like this according width or height

```
height: size.height*0.1,
```

Comment: It didn't work! It's giving the same error.

Comment: bro remove material app you need to use material app only user scaffold then its will work for you